# Caught in my net

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

Would you like to see what I caught today?

Take a look inside my net!

It's a robot of some sort, I don't know which one though.

```
OOB       OOY       OOY
GGW       GGY       GGY
GWG       GWO       GWO

WRY  RBR  WRY  GOO  WRY  GOO
OWY  ROB  OWY  BOR  OWY  BOR
OBB  OOG  OBY  RBR  YBW  BGW
```

Hint 0.5:

> The [pattern](/questions/tagged/pattern) tag is no longer there as the puzzle is not really a pattern.

Hint 1:

> I think the robot has a specific name.

Comment: I wasn't sure what tags to put, if someone can help me (without knowing the solution) that would be great!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Where is this puzzle from? You need to cite the place you've taken the puzzle from if it's not your own.

Comment: @Deusovi it's my own puzzle, I know there's not much to it.

Comment: Ah, alright! It's a really nice puzzle - you just said you "didn't know" which robot it was, so I thought it had come from somewhere else.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Building on Dmihawk's answer. The letters depict

> colours in a Rubik's cube. Three 9x9 boxes depict the three visible sides. As such, there are three different cube states visible, with some series of rotations between each one.
>
>  [image]
>
>  Looks like "rotate right side twice, then underside twice" if I have this right.

With some help from @kanoo in the comments...

> You can represent two right turns as "R2"... Two down turns as "D2"... making the robot **R2-D2**.

Comment: Hey buddy I know the answer but I ain't claiming credit for it because you are 0.2 seconds away from it. think about how to represent the right side and the number of turns, then the bottom side rot13(be qbja fvqr) and that number of turns. The answer you get should be a robot from a fairly popular franchise.

Comment: @kanoo aaaa I think I see what you mean...

Comment: Nicely done! I had completely missed the Rubik's cube reference

Comment: This answer gets the green tick! I was thinking if another hint would make it too easy, and I suppose it would have.

Answer (score 6):

It's not an answer (yet) but...

> Substituting each letter for a colour (R for Red, O for Orange etc.) yields an interesting pattern

Like so:

> [image: Robots]

Some thoughts

> We can break the shapes down into three distinct categories. The top row, and each alternating one in the bottom row.
> So from left to right, we see the following transformations:
> (1) Replace top right B with Y and bottom right G with O, then no change
> (2) Replace bottom right B with Y, then replace bottom left O with Y and bottom right Y with W
> (3) Rotate 180 degrees, then replace bottom left R with B, bottom middle B with G and bottom right Y with W

Comment: You're on the right track. I removed the pattern tag, because it wasn't exactly a pattern. Keep thinking!

Answer (score -3):

> Is Doraemon the answer?
>  The only robot with name I can think of is Doraemon.

Comment: You gotta actually go through the puzzle and explain reasoning when you answer a question.